# Deleting A Row In Excel From VBE

Tags: vb.net, excel, vb.net-2010

I have got some code that looks for a record in an excel file that contains the same characters as a textbox. I then need to delete that row, but I am not sure how to do this. Please could anybody help me?
Here is my code:

```
Dim oXL As Excel.Application
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oRng As Excel.Range
    'create object and open workbook
    oXL = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    oXL.Workbooks.Open(CreateAdmin.FileLocation + "\DVDRental.xls")

    'open worksheet
    oSheet = oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Logins")

    oRng = oSheet.Range("A1:A100")

    Dim blankspace As Integer = 1

    Do Until oRng(blankspace, 2).value() = ""
        If oRng(blankspace, 2).value() <> "" Then
            blankspace = blankspace + 1
        End If
    Loop

    Dim introw As Integer = 1
    Dim user As String
    Dim username As String = TextBox1.Text

    If username = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter A User ID")
    Else
        Do
            user = oRng(introw, 2).value()


            If user = username Then


                oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
                oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Close()

                Exit Do
            Else : introw = introw + 1

            End If
        Loop Until introw = blankspace

        oRng = Nothing
        oSheet = Nothing
        oXL.Quit()
        oXL = Nothing
        TextBox1.Clear()
```

Comment: This code wouldn't compile in VBA. Is it possible you wrote it in (or got it from) a different language? Perhaps .NET?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Visual Basic

Comment: Okay, I've proposed an edit to your tags so that it's picked up by the .NET gang.

Answer (score 0):

The following example removes rows with a first column value equal to zero. Modify it to suit your need. 
As you can imagine, removing a row "repositions" all the others below, so I found it easier to work upward, rather than track the changes.

```
    For RowDelete = Worksheets(TargetSheet).UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

        If Cells(RowDelete, 1).Value = 0 Then
            Rows(RowDelete).Delete
        End If

    Next RowDelete
```

(If this runs too slowly try ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
and Application.ScreenUpdating = False before, and then again, but True after the loop.)

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try!